# How can a user create an entry that is only enabled for 1 locale?

Tags: localization

How can a user create an entry that is only enabled for 1 locale?

I would like a German user to only be able to publish an entry in the `de` locale.

I have set the permissions for the user to only publish in the `de` locale, but, when this user saves a new entry, the locale is then enabled for every locale.

I have tried disabling each locale in the channel settings, but, then the user is required to enable it for their own locale when publishing.

[Similar question here](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/only-publish-user-generated-entries-in-current-locale), but no answer yet.

Comment: Hi Joep. What's the default locale?

Comment: `en`, though posting from the German user will enable it for all locales, not just `en`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have tried disabling each locale in the channel settings, but, then the user is required to enable it for their own locale when publishing.

That's the only way to pull off what you're looking for in Craft 2.

With the upcoming Craft 3 refactoring, it would be much easier to pull of with a new event that a plugin could listen to and alter the behavior.

Feel free to make a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) as well.